# How to Create and center multiple imageview horizontally and when space is full overlap them evenly for android?

Tags: android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

So I am in the process of creating a card game and have gotten to the point of where I can create the deck of cards, shuffle the cards and even deal the cards.  I have all the UI'S built to the point before dealing the cards.

I know what I want in a layout and know how to do it providing that I knew the unknown like as to how many cards each of the 4 players will have.

I will have 2 UI screens.

The first screen will display all 4 players and next to the player will be overlapping card backs so that way everyone will know how many cards each player has and it will somehow highlight the person with the current winning hand.

The issue is the 2nd UI screen.  When it is each players turn they will tap their name and the 2nd UI will show them Their name and then all the cards they have so far and a deal button so they can deal another card.

If the player has 1 card I want the imageview centered in the defined card space.  And when they add a second card for it to adjust to make both cards centered.  When there is no more space I still want the cards to be centered but overlapping.

Can someone explain or point me in the right direction on how to create the layout so that way when I add the code to add additional cards it will automatically center them all horizontally in the space and overlapping when necessary?

Images below show 1, 2, 3 cards and then cards overlapped because of no more space for individual cards.  I just need to know how to create the layout so that way I can dynmically add imageviews and as imageviews are added it creates the effects in the images below.

One Card Centered
[image]

Two Cards Centered
[image]

3 Cards Centered
[image]

More Cards than spaced, so cards overlap centered.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps providing a few images of what you will help people in ensuring what you mean my horizontally centered (e.g. what it looks like with one, two, three, and eight cards).

Comment: There can be up to a max of 25 cards dealt to one player in total.  I know I can do it the hard way and create all 25 views and load each view dependent upon the amount of cards the player has, but there has to be an easier way to do it than that.